# HDFS write failed use python hdfs 2.6.0 package

Tags: python

```
def hdfs_copy_stream(src, dst, namenode=None):
    try:
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        offset = 0
        clt = get_client(src, namenode)
        with clt.read(src, offset=offset, chunk_size=2 ** 16) as reader:
            with clt.write(dst, overwrite=True) as writer:
                for chunk in reader:
                    md5.update(chunk)
                    offset += len(chunk)
                    writer.write(chunk)
        md5_value = md5.hexdigest()
        print('md5 = {}, length = {}'.format(md5_value, offset))
        return RunState.Done, (md5_value, offset)
    except Exception as e:
        print("copy file {} to {} failed: {}".format(src, dst, e))
        return RunState.Error, None
```

I implemented a copy method like this.
It works well for large files, but for small files with tens of KB, sometimes the function runs successfully, but the target path of HDFS is indeed a file with a length of 0. I checked it for a long time and found no problem.
When I add time.sleep like this:

```
offset += len(chunk)
writer.write(chunk)
time.sleep(0.001)
```

Problem solved.
I really don't know why, so I'm here to ask for your help.

Comment: Also, I used the Requests library for 2.26.0.